# SHA1 error implementation in C

Tags: c, openssl, sha1

I have been working on getting the sha1() function working from openssl/sha.h however I am getting random output and some warning. I have read quite a bit and tried some of the example codes but I get warning on all of it and it doesn't display correctly.

Here is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main() 
{ 
const unsigned char data[] = "Hello, World";
unsigned long length = sizeof(data);
unsigned char  hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1(data, length, hash);
printf("%02x \n", hash);
return 0;

}
```

Below is the warning I am getting:

```
sha.c: In function ‘main’:
sha.c:12: warning: ‘SHA1’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/sha.h:124)
sha.c:13: warning: format ‘%02x’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type   ‘unsigned char *’
sha.c:13: warning: format ‘%02x’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned char *’
```

When I run it and I get the output:
    62652b34

Any help would be great!

Comment: If you compare the result to some test bench data, make sure the length is correct. In most cases length of "Hello, World" should be 12, but here I think it's 13, as sizeof() counts the ascii zero character too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also took me a while before I figured it all out. The best way is to use EVP, it provides generic functions for almost everything.

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
```

You need to call this im main before calling you hash function. To initialize your hashes. Otherwise openssl will complain that the algorithm is not available.

```
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
```

**mode** must be "SHA256", "SHA512", "SHA1" as string.
**dataToHash** is the input, **dataSize** is the size of the input,
**outHashed** should already be allocated, the hash will be written there

```
unsigned int hash(const char *mode, const char* dataToHash, size_t dataSize, unsigned char* outHashed) {
    unsigned int md_len = -1;
    const EVP_MD *md = EVP_get_digestbyname(mode);
    if(NULL != md) {
        EVP_MD_CTX mdctx;
        EVP_MD_CTX_init(&mdctx);
        EVP_DigestInit_ex(&mdctx, md, NULL);
        EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, dataToHash, dataSize);
        EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&mdctx, outHashed, &md_len);
        EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&mdctx);
    }
    return md_len;
}
```

A use example (this is not tested, I use the above code in a c++ wrapper)

```
const char *inData = "test data2";
unsigned char outHash[20]; // output is already allocated
hash("SHA1", inData, 10, outHash);
```

---

You shouldn't use the SHA1 method directly it is deprecated (your code could blow up with the next version).
If you want to use your version you need to print each char as hex:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    printf("%02x", hash[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help. I am having the deprecated issues with the evp.h also. Is there something different I am suppose to use other then that one now?

Comment: @user1626342 hmm, that is very strange you should not have any issue with evp being deprecated. Can you post the code/warning ?

Comment: I guess since I was using mac OS I had to add a bunch of if headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dump the entire buffer that way. you need to loop it, such as below. The value you're getting for your output is actually the *address* of the `hash` buffer, which is clearly not what you're looking for. You want the hex-bytes in the buffer dumped as text

So...

```
int main()
{
    const unsigned char data[] = "Hello, World";
    unsigned long length = sizeof(data);
    unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA1(data, length, hash);

    int i=0;
    for (;i< sizeof(hash)/sizeof(hash[0]);++i)
        printf("%02x \n", hash[i]);

    return 0;

}
```

Regarding your warnings, the deprecation is because this interface is out-dated for performing the crypto-op you're attempting (SHA1). There are newer interfaces in OpenSSL that are current. Consider the EVP interface specifically.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%02u \n", hash);
```

Remove warnings by printing unsigned char

Comment: This isn't right. This will send the array address of hash to be printed as an unsigned min-two-diget int prefaced by 0 if the value is < 10 (which I almost assure you it will be). The only difference between this and the OP's code is this prints the address as unsigned int rather than hex. neither is correct.